# Getting something Indented and I do not understand why

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, paragraphs

Please consider the following LaTex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
% define the title
\title{A Math Problems}
\author{Robert~J.~Sherry}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent
Problem:
\newline
Fit a least-square line to the data given below with $x$ as the independent variable and $y$ as the dependent variable.
\newline
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|llllll|} \hline
        x & 3 & 5 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 11  \\ \hline
        y & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 8  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Answer:
\newline
Problem:
```

When the above LaTex code (and I did truncate it) is rendered the line: Answer: is indented. I tired putting right before Answer: but that generated an error. I do not want the line indented. What should I do?

Comment: `[H]` assumes it comes between paragraphs. You shouldn't really ever need `\newline` or `\noindent` in a document, I would add `\usepackage{parskip}` so paragraph indention is zero and just use blank lines instead of `\newline.

Comment: It would be simpler just to use `tabular` here, the `table` environment isn't doing anything useful/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Adding the line \usepackage{parskip} solved my problem. Maybe you should post that as an answer so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[H]` assumes it comes between paragraphs. You shouldn't really ever need `\newline` or `\noindent` in a document, I would add

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

so paragraph indention is zero and just use blank lines instead of `\newline`.